# Python having issues to implement eval + high order functions/ decorator

Tags: python, schedule

I hope someone will be able to help me with my issue:
Working with `schedule` module, according documentation job needs to be called like this:

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
I need to create a  wrapper function to pass instead `(10).minutes.do` dynamic values according documentation from this module( `(10).minutes.do or ().hour.do` e t.c.) from args.
And intead job needs to call my function with parameters `copy_from_to(absolute_path_to_the_file: str, destination: str)` .
I'd like to get and run something like that using eval and high order function or a decorator:

```
def schedule_task(*given_time: str,function):
     eval(('schedule.every')+''.join(map(str, given_time)+function()))
```

to get something like this:

```
eval(('schedule.every')+''.join(map(str, given_time)+function()))
```

When i'm trying to run

```
schedule_task('(10).minutes.do',copy_from_to('C:\Projects\python\comcast\paramiko\\1.txt','/c/'))
```

but i'm geiitng error: `schedule_task() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'function'`

What I'm doing wrong? How should I implement that?
Thank you so much for any help.

Thank you for all your comments, i'll try to clarify my intensions: i wanna create function for copying file using ssh when i could dynamically pass which file i wanna copy and where and also how often i wanna do that func(file_patn, destination, how often). I still couldn't implement that. Maybe there is easier way to do that? Thank you – Vladimir 14 hours ago
This is my function
`def schedule_task(*given_time: str, function): eval_func = (('schedule.every') + ''.join(map(str, given_time))+'('+f'{function()}'+')') print(eval_func)`

when i'm trying to run

```
schedule_task('(10).minutes.do', function=lambda: copy_from_to( 'C:\Projects\python\comcast\paramiko\1.txt', '/c/')) and print it, i'm getting schedule.every(10).minutes.do(None)
```

but instead none should be a lambda function above, why it doesn't happen?

Comment: I suspect there is an easier way to do what you want.  What are you trying to *achieve*?

Comment: also consider using `apscheduler`, I've found it to be better for scheduling tasks

Comment: You are trying to give a function itself as an parameter in another function. Instead you can put the `copy_from_to` function directly inside the `schedule_task` function like, `eval(('schedule.every')+''.join(map(str, given_time)+copy_from_to('C:\Projects\python\comcast\paramiko\\1.txt','/c/') ))`. For creating a statements with dynamic variable name `exec` will be ok. `given_time = '(10).minutes.do'
exec(f"schedule.every{given_time}(job)")`

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, i'll  try to clarify my intensions: i wanna create function for copying file using ssh when i could dynamically pass which file i wanna copy and where and also how often i wanna do that func(file_patn, destination, how often). I still couldn't implement that. Maybe there is easier way to do that? Thank you

Comment: This is my function 
def schedule_task(*given_time: str, function):
    eval_func = (('schedule.every') +
                 ''.join(map(str, given_time))+'('+f'{function()}'+')')
    print(eval_func)

when i'm trying to run schedule_task('(10).minutes.do', function=lambda: copy_from_to(
    'C:\Projects\python\comcast\paramiko\1.txt', '/c/')) and print it, i'm getting schedule.every(10).minutes.do(None), but instead none should be a lambda function above, why it doesn't happen?